# What's the expected behavior of open(name, O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY, mode)?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, posix, bsd

Despite a careful read of [the related standard documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), I can't understand what's the expected behavior in POSIX compliant systems when a `open` system call is invoked with flags including `O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY`.

The standard specifies that

> If O_CREAT and O_DIRECTORY are set **and** the requested access mode is neither O_WRONLY nor O_RDWR, the result is unspecified.

However it does not specify the behavior of the system with neither `(O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_WRONLY)` nor `(O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_RDWR)`. Indeed (as far as I can understand) the behavior on `EISDIR` only apply to **existing** directories.

In the section related to O_CREATE, the standard specifies that, when the named file does not exist,

> if O_DIRECTORY **is not set** the file shall be created as a regular file; [...]

but again it does not specify what will happen if `O_DIRECTORY` is set too.

I've looked the manual pages of both [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?open%202%20NetBSD-current) (which notoriously cares a lot about POSIX compliance) and [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) (which is a widely used system, despite not actually a POSIX one) but I can't find any clarification.

Is it correct to say that the use of both flags is unspecified?
And if so, what's the most common behavior?

Is `open(name, O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY, mode)`  equivalent to `mkdir` on any POSIX compliant OS?

Comment: Note that you should include one of `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` in the open flags (or possibly `O_EXEC` or `O_SEARCH`).  Historically, omitting those is equivalent to specifying `O_RDONLY` (it is normally 0; `O_WRONLY` is normally 1, and `O_RDWR` is normally 2), but these are not bit values.  (The `O_EXEC` and `O_SEARCH` options specified by POSIX complicate life, but neither Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) nor macOS 10.12.6 supports either of them.)  I see now where I got my 'faulty' code from — I copied your `open()` command without realizing I wasn't strictly abiding by the rules.

Comment: In the rationale section of the POSIX specification for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), it says: _In addition, the `open()` function refuses to open non-directories if the O_DIRECTORY flag is set. This avoids race conditions whereby a user might compromise the system by substituting a hard link to a sensitive file (e.g., a device or a FIFO) while a privileged application is running, where opening a file even for read access might have undesirable side-effects._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

netbsd itself contains the following in vn_open:

```
if ((fmode & (O_CREAT | O_DIRECTORY)) == (O_CREAT | O_DIRECTORY))
        return EINVAL;
```

so any combination with these 2 is straight up rejected.

in linux it's a little bit more hairy, but any trivial test will show you that the directory is not created either, but you can end up with a file

for kicks i also checked freebsd, which never ends up creating anything with O_DIRECTORY in the first place

if what you are looking for is a mkdir which gives you back the fd, i'm afraid there is nothing of the sort. on the other hand you should be able to safely open with O_DIRECTORY anything you mkdir'ed.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have misunderstood what `O_DIRECTORY` is meant for. It's not to *create* a directory but to ensure the "file" opened by `open(2)` is a directory.

> O_DIRECTORY
>   If path resolves to a non-directory file, fail and set errno to [ENOTDIR].

That's precisely how [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) documents it (quoted above).

> However it does not specify the behavior of the system with neither (O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_WRONLY) nor (O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_RDWR)

The behaviour of `O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_WRONLY` and `O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_RDWR` is equivalent to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY` and `O_CREAT|O_RDWR`
respectively provided the *pathname* (first argument to open(2)) is a directory. The presence of `O_DIRECTORY` is to ensure the file being opened
is a directory - it doesn't affect anything else.

> Is it correct to say that the use of both flags is unspecified? And if so, what's the most common behavior?

It means the behaviour of the specific *combination* `O_CREAT | O_DIRECTORY` isn't specified; doesn't mean using the individual flags
(with or without other flags) is unspecified.

> Is open(name, O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY, mode) equivalent to mkdir on any POSIX compliant OS?

Not at all. That's why it's left as *unspecified*. On Linux, [it's definitely not](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) - a regular file is created:

> When both O_CREAT and O_DIRECTORY are specified in flags and the file
>   specified by pathname does not exist, open() will create a regular
>   file (i.e., O_DIRECTORY is ignored).

To create a directory, you'd use [`mkdir(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html).

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far are not correct. Implementations are free to support directory creation via `O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_WRONLY` or `O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY|O_RDWR`, but they are not required to.
This was clarified in 2014, as you can see in the [bug tracker of the Austin group](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=847):

> `open("/path/to/existing/directory", O_CREAT)` should fail with `EISDIR`, but implementations should be allowed to support creating and opening a directory via `open("/path/to/directory", O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY)` as an extension

with the following rationale:

> The standard does not specify the behavior when `open()` is called with `O_CREAT|O_RDONLY` (or `O_CREAT|O_SEARCH`) on an existing directory. Additionally, some systems want to allow creation of directories using the `open()` function. This should be an allowed, but not required, extension.

The wording you cited from the [current version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) of the standard

> If O_CREAT and O_DIRECTORY are set and the requested access mode is neither O_WRONLY nor O_RDWR, the result is unspecified.

was precisely one of the changes made to allow it.

One of reasons for allowing this, as described by [Rich Felkner](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/9451), is, that it would provide an interface for atomically creating and opening a directory.

However, I don't know, if any POSIX implementation out there does actually provide directory creation via `open`.

Comment: "The answers so far are not correct." - please be specific about what is wrong with previous answers.

Comment: It seems unfortunate that O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY is not mandated to create a directory as `subfd = openat(dirfd, "name", O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY, mode)` seems like it would be highly useful.