# How to get the mode a file was opened in C (LINUX)

Tags: c, fopen, fcntl

I want to implement a function that gets as parameter a `FILE*`, that is already open in write mode (`a`, `a+`, `w`, `w+` etc), and reads the contents of that file. The problem here is that the file is already locked (because of the `fopen`) and I need to close it before starting reading.
However, after I have read the file I need to reopen it just like it was before my function was called.

Thus, I need both the **file name** and the **mode** the `fopen` was  called with, initially.

I was able to get the *file name*. However the mode seems to be tricky.
Since now I was able to get the **mode code** using the code below.

```
int fd = fileno(file_pointer);
int mode = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
```

Unfortunately, there is inconsistency among systems (same open mode -> different mode codes). Is the method shown above an actual way to get the mode a file was open in? Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: It would be simpler to not modify the FILE* argument and open a second time the file in read mode.

Comment: Why not just flush the file, then open it separately for reading? Why do you need to close it?

Comment: Why not open the file in a read/write mode in the first place? Then you can use `ftell` and `fseek` to restore the original condition.

Comment: Note that if the file stream is opened in plain `"w"` mode or `"a"` mode, you won't be able to read it using that file stream.  Also note that on Unix-like systems, `fopen()` does not lock the file — any file can be opened many times.  Using `fcntl()` is about as good as it gets.

Comment: You might find useful information at [What's the expected behavior of `open(name, O_CREAT|O_DIRECTORY, mode)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818628)  It's more about file descriptors than file streams, but you're already looking at descriptors via `fileno()`.  Remember, Unix does not distinguish between binary and text mode.  Are you working on a Windows platform?  The rules there may be different, and it does distinguish between binary and text mode.

Comment: You are right! The problem is that the string is not saved in the file instantly when fwrite is called rather than when the file is closed.